# Using a JS function to apply a new fill style to multiple SVGs does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, svg

[Here is my codepen](http://codepen.io/lixelart/pen/MwLPVj?), it's got a ton of comments in JS section since that is a core part of what I am learning still.

**When I use "getELementsByClassName" or "querySelectorAll" to apply a new fill to an SVG, the console gives me errors. "getElementById" works, however I have multiple SVGs I would like to apply the change to.**

If you press and hold on "click me", you see 3 lightning bolts. The program runs a code when you click to generate a hex value which is then applied to the 3 solid lightning bolts, and eventually the background of the page. The lightning bolts are SVGs. I have given each a shared class (".solids"), and unique IDs (#solids1, etc). However, using this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName (".solids").style.fill = "#" + newHexString;
```

...no changes are applied to the svgs at all. (Line 48 in the JS pane.) The console gives this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fill' of undefined"

Likewise, I have seen a few suggestions here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere to use .querySelector and .querySelectorAll and neither work. (Line 51, JS pane.) I also see a similar console error when trying this.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".solids").style.fill = "#" + newHexString;
```

But a long list of 'getElementById' works just fine. :/

I would love thoughts as to what I can do more efficiently, and why these other two routes don't work?

Comment: just checked out your example and it seems to work fine. When I press the button, the bolts are shown in a certain color and once I release the mouse, the background changes color to what the bolts were before.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I switched it back to using 'getElementById' so that I could continue working on other aspects. But the lines that didn't work are still there, simply commented out. I've reverted back to 'querySelectorAll' and it fails to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelectorAll` return (respectively) a HTMLCollection and a NodeList object, that's why the property `style` is undefined (there is no such property on HTMLCollection and NodeList objects) and you get the error because you try to access the `fill` property on an undefined value. The `getElementById` method returns an instance of Element (not a collection), that's why the `style` property is defined and you don't get any error.

I'm surprised `querySelector` doesn't work as it actually returns an element (like `getElementById`). Are you sure you got an error with it?

To apply the changes on all the elements, you need to iterate over the list returned by `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll` and set the `style.fill` property on each of them, like so:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('my-element');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.fill = '#' + newHexString;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. 

So I switched back to querySelector (instead of querySelectorAll). And I only see 1 pair of lightning bolts rather than 3 as it does if I list each one by Id. You are right though, I don't see an error. 

Does this mean that querySelector will only grab the first item with that selector?

[Here is the codepen again](http://codepen.io/lixelart/pen/MwLPVj), with querySelector grabbing set of bolts rather than all 3.

Comment: Yep! At this point I guess still I don't understand why "querySelector" doesn't grab _all_ of the elements with that class name in my original pen.

Comment: `querySelector` returns the first element that matches the CSS selector. See [Document.querySelector on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) :)